# Updating multi-value fields using REST API

Tags: rest

I searched previous posts and the closest to my question is:
[Updating Lookup Values with the REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84560/updating-lookup-values-with-the-rest-api/100212#100212) however I am using the cross-domain library and my update query uses ValidateUpdateListItem method. In my query data the body property is something like this:

`"{   'formValues':[" +
    "{'FieldName':'CustomerID',       'FieldValue': '" + dataObject.CustomerID + "'}, " +
    "{'FieldName':'RelatedForms',     'FieldValue': '" + <?????> + "'}, " +
    "{'FieldName':'ItemID',           'FieldValue': '" + dataObject.ItemID + "'}" +
    "], 'bNewDocumentUpdate': false }";`

In the  part I tried something like `{ "results": [1, 3] }` but doesn't work. Any ideas?