# How do I send data to a lookup field with ReST? SP2013

Tags: 2013, rest, lookup-column, ajax, updatelistitems

I've been working with a jQuery AJAX call to post data to one of my SharePoint lists.

One of the fields in this list is a look-up field. In forming my JSON data to push to the list I was able to push data to each field with the exception of the look-up field.

How do I push data into a lookup field?

I know I need to push the target list's ID to the look-up field, but have gotten hung up on just how to format the data.

Comment: With search engines and within StackExhange, I've found many partial answers. Here I hope to build ready reference for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from this question:[Updating Lookup Values with the REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84560/updating-lookup-values-with-the-rest-api)

```
var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
            "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Sales Opportunities')/Items(5)",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "__metadata": { type: "SP.Data.Sales_x0020_OpportunitiesListItem" },
            StateId: 2
        }),
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": item.__metadata.etag,
            "X-Http-Method": "PATCH"
        }
    });
```

Comment: Then second answer for that post summarizes what I found well. I will upvote it. Thank you for the link. I'll use 'updating' in my future searches along these lines. That seems to be the key to finding this result in the search bar. The key is the single value vs multiple value and the 'results' array.

Comment: Appending 'Id' to the lookupfieldname is essential as well. It seems to have been missed in the above referenced answer, but having paid a bounty, I've not the reputation to comment.