# How to update list item with lookup (People and Group) column using REST post method

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, site-column, json

I want to update a list item with **People and Group** column.

The list has 4 columns:

- Title
- Description
- ProsessOwner
- ProsessContributer

I am  not able to add/update through a **REST POST** method, since I am getting an **error on these** two **columns:** **ProsessOwner, ProsessContributer.** If i remove them both from the query string, the rest query works.

This is the returned error:

`A node of type 'PrimitiveValue' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the entries of a feed. A 'StartObject' or 'EndArray' node was expected.`

And my code :

```
 $scope.saveNewPage = function () {
        var err = false;
        var title = $scope.newPage.title;
        var descr = $scope.newPage.description;
        var pOwnerID = { 'results': [processOwnerID,11] };
        var pContrID = { 'results': [processContributerID,11] };
        var data = { "Title": title, "Description": descr, "ProsessOwner": pOwnerID, "ProcessContributer": pContrID };

        ppService.addnewPage(data).then(function (data) {
            close(data.d.Id);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log('Feilet med å opprette ny Side');
        });

    }

var addnewPage = function (data) {
        var addData = {
            __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.GNPagesListItem' },
            Title: data.Title,
            Description: data.Description,
            ProsessOwner: data.ProsessOwner,
            ProcessContributer: data.ProcessContributer
        };

        var url = listEndPoint + "/GetByTitle('GNPages')/Items";
        return baseSvc.postRequest(addData, url);
    };

        var postRequest = function (data, url) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: baseUrl + url,
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .success(function (result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            })
            .error(function (result, status) {
                deferred.reject(status);
                console.log(result)
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

## Edit

I just edited my list "Person or Group" column setting to only allow only **single value selection** and the REST query worked fine with the code below:

```
 var addnewPage = function (data) {
        var addData = {
            __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.GNPagesListItem' },
            Title: data.Title,
            Description: data.Description,
            ProsessOwnerId: 10,
            ProcessContributerId: 11
        };

        var url = listEndPoint + "/GetByTitle('GNPages')/Items";
        return baseSvc.postRequest(addData, url);
    };
```

But as soon as I changed column back to the previous setting ( *allow multiple selections*), and change the REST query to send an array of id's like [10,11], I get the same error:

`A node of type 'PrimitiveValue' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the entries of a feed. A 'StartObject' or 'EndArray' node was expected.`

Comment: I fixed this with sending an array for multiple selection like this: {results: [10,11]};

Comment: Hey please take a look to my answer in case it also works and can be marked as alternative answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are missing something in this step.

```
var addData = {
__metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.GNPagesListItem' },
Title: data.Title,
Description: data.Description,
ProsessOwnerId: data.ProsessOwner,
ProcessContributerId: data.ProcessContributer
};
```

To update a people or group field, instead of **ProsessOwner** or **ProcessContributer** the nomenclature should be **ProsessOwnerId** and **ProcessContributerId**. Most of us will miss the suffix 'Id' with the internal name while updating a people or group filed. And the value for the field should be User Id of the user in the Site.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is some mismatch in your **JSON** or **data** variable.

Please check whether for "**data.ProsessOwner**" and "**data.ProcessContributer**" you are getting correct ID's.

please refer this answer - [Updating Lookup Values with the REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84560/updating-lookup-values-with-the-rest-api)

Comment: I fixed it like this for multiple values:  {results: [10,11]}; , you need to send an array like this. or only an id of user.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution for you, in scenarios you want to update a people column [mypeoplecol] through rest / spfx:

- Single value people column: 
  `[mypeoplecol]Id = X`, where X is a [number] type value.
- Multiple value people column: `[mypeoplecol]Id = {results:[X, Y, ...]}`, where X, Y, ... are [number] type value.

> Take into account that you may need to leverage the `ensureUser` service, in order to ensure the target(s) user(s) do have and ID on that site.